# do make arraylist from the array having value by javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have `a = [1,2,3,4,5]`
        `b = [2,3,5,6,1,7]`
        `c = [1,2,43,67,8,7]`
        `d = []`
`e = []`
`f = []`
`g = [5,8,9,3]`
i want `x = [a,b,c,g]` with use of jquery

Comment: i had used probability logic .... so now as its code refactoring time i have to comeup with new logic

Comment: what happens with `d`, `e`, `f`? how should the result look like?

Comment: I want just to forget those who does not have any value

Answer (score 1):

A solution in plain javascript with [`Array#filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```js
function clean(array) {
    return array.filter(function (a) { return a.length; });
}

var a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    b = [2, 3, 5, 6, 1, 7],
    c = [1, 2, 43, 67, 8, 7],
    d = [],
    e = [],
    f = [],
    g = [5, 8, 9, 3],
    x = clean([a, b, c, d, e, f, g]);

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(x, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using [JQuery.grep()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.grep/) to filter each array, the first argument is the array to filter, the second is a function to process each item against (the first argument in the function is the item itself and the second is the index), the third argument is used tu invert the filter (optional), so you can select each item that doesn't pass the filter:

```js
var a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    b = [2, 3, 5, 6, 1, 7],
    c = [1, 2, 43, 67, 8, 7],
    d = [],
    e = [],
    f = [],
    g = [5, 8, 9, 3];

var result = $.grep([a,b,c,d,e,f,g], function(n){return n.length > 0});

document.write('<pre>'+ JSON.stringify(result) +'</pre>')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Why is not working? JQuery,grep() filter the elements in an array, so you can exclude the empty arrays that you have, this is not what you want?

Comment: What's wrong with this solution. It's giving you the results without blank array and you want the same. Isn't it?